# Transffering data from multiple arraylist to a multidimensional array

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, arraylist, split

I need help transferring data from 4 `ArrayLists` to a multi-dimensional array. Please look at the comments in my variables.

I need to put the data from all the arraylists into `card[][]` in this format:

```
card[][] = {{questions,answers,category,essay}};
```

codes:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Test {
    static JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

     //these need to go into card[][]
    static List<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> essays = new ArrayList<String>();


    static String[][] card;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OpenFile();

    }

    public static void OpenFile() {
        int retrival = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (retrival == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            String line;

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    chooser.getSelectedFile()))) {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] splitted = line.split("Question: ");
                    String[] splittedAnswer = line.split("Answer: ");
                    String[] splittedCategory = line.split("Category: ");
                    String[] splittedEssay = line
                            .split("Essay Question Possibility: ");

                    if (splittedAnswer.length == 2) {
                        answers.add(splittedAnswer[1]);
                    } else if (splitted.length == 2) {
                        questions.add(splitted[1]);

                    } else if (splittedCategory.length == 2) {
                        categories.add(splittedCategory[1]);

                    } else if (splittedEssay.length == 2) {
                        essays.add(splittedEssay[1]);

                    }

                }
                br.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow... what are you trying to accomplish here? And why can't you just use something simple, like an arraylist of a class that contains questions, answers, category, essays?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the array list are of same size you can do as below,

```
String[][] card = new String[4][questions.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) {
    card[0][i] = questions.get(i);
    card[1][i] = answers.get(i);
    card[2][i] = categories.get(i);
    card[3][i] = essays.get(i);
}
```

***Suggestion***

But I advice you to use Object oriented data structure for holding your data. Using multiple list or 2D arrays are not advisable.

You can simply define your structure as

```
public class Card {
    String question;
    String answer;
    String categories;
    String essay;
}
```

And you have have the list as.

```
List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Cards>();
```

Comment: I agree with the suggestion, if your writing in an object oriented language, why not leverage organizational advantages it offers

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
            String  card[][] ;
            List<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> essays = new ArrayList<String>();
            questions.add("11");
            questions.add("12");
            questions.add("13");

            answers.add("21");
            answers.add("22");
            answers.add("23");

            categories.add("31");
            categories.add("32");
            categories.add("33");

            essays.add("41");
            essays.add("42");
            essays.add("43");

            card=new String [essays.size()][4];
            for(int i=0;i<questions.size();i++)
            {
               card[i][0]=questions.get(i);
               card[i][1]=answers.get(i);
               card[i][2]=categories.get(i);
               card[i][3]=essays.get(i);
            }
```

Output will be

**{{"11","21","31","41"}, {"12","22","32","42"}, {"13","23","33","43"}, ...};**

Answer (score 0):

I think that all arraylists have one size. If 'not' you should first find minimal size of arraylists and then use it instead questions.size():

```
card = new String[questions.size()][4];

for (int i = 0; i < card.length; i++){
    card[i][0] = questions.get(i);
    card[i][1] = answers.get(i);
    card[i][2] = categories.get(i);
    card[i][3] = essays.get(i);
}
```

Result will be like this:

{{"q1","a1","c1","e1"}, {"q2","a2","c2","e2"}, {"q3","a3","c3","e3"}, {"q4","a4","c4","e4"}, ...};